# AutoMapper converters fail for null values

Tags: c#, automapper, deprecated

**Note: this question is now out of date and only applies to old versions of AutoMapper. The bug referred to here has been fixed.**

---

**Problem:**

I have an AutoMapper converter that takes a `Nullable<bool>`/`bool?` and returns a `string`. I apply this globally to my profile, and it works for `true` and `false` but not for `null`.

**Here is what I have in my AutoMapper profile:**

```
CreateMap<bool?, string>()
    .ConvertUsing<NullableBoolToLabel>();
```

**And here is the converter class:**

```
public class NullableBoolToLabel : ITypeConverter<bool?, string>
{
    public string Convert(bool? source)
    {
        if (source.HasValue)
        {
            if (source.Value)
                return "Yes";
            else
                return "No";
        }
        else
            return "(n/a)";
    }
}
```

**Example that demonstrates problem**

```
public class Foo
{
    public bool? IsFooBarred { get; set; }
}

public class FooViewModel
{
    public string IsFooBarred { get; set; }
}

public class TryIt
{
    public TryIt()
    {
        Mapper.CreateMap<bool?, string>().ConvertUsing<NullableBoolToLabel>();
        Mapper.CreateMap<Foo, FooViewModel>();

        // true (succeeds)
        var foo1 = new Foo { IsFooBarred = true };
        var fooViewModel1 = Mapper.Map<Foo, FooViewModel>(foo1);
        Debug.Print("[{0}]", fooViewModel1.IsFooBarred); // prints: [Yes] 

        // false (succeeds)
        var foo2 = new Foo { IsFooBarred = false };
        var fooViewModel2 = Mapper.Map<Foo, FooViewModel>(foo2);
        Debug.Print("[{0}]", fooViewModel2.IsFooBarred); // prints: [No] 

        // null (fails)
        var foo3 = new Foo { IsFooBarred = null };
        var fooViewModel3 = Mapper.Map<Foo, FooViewModel>(foo3);
        Debug.Print("[{0}]", fooViewModel3.IsFooBarred); // prints: []
                                                   // should print: [(n/a)]
    }
}
```

**Questions:**

1. Is this a bug or by design?
2. If it's by design, what is the reasoning behind it working this way?
3. Can you recommend a workaround?

Comment: Nope, this is a bug, and I'm hunting it down as I type this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was a bug in AutoMapper and has since been fixed.

The `ITypeConverter` interface has also changed since this question was asked. The converter would now look like this:

```
public class NullableBoolToLabel : ITypeConverter<bool?, string>
{
    public string Convert(ResolutionContext context)
    {
        var source = (bool?)context.SourceValue;
        if (source.HasValue)
        {
            if (source.Value)
                return "Yes";
            else
                return "No";
        }
        else
            return "(n/a)";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you need to specify a ConvertUsing for the Map?  Otherwise, I'm not sure how it would know how to use the IsFooBarred member of the Foo class.  But I'm not familar with the Mapper, and perhaps it can figure this out (it does seem to in the first two cases).

If you put a breakpoint in Convert does it get hit (in the debugger) in any of the 3 cases?

Comment: This is actually a really old question. It was a bug in AutoMapper that was fixed a while ago. Thanks for your answer anyway :)